# How to hide last table row with specific class in table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, hide

I have a page with a series of tables with the following structure

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>2</th>
     <th>Position</th>
     <th>Names</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="station-12 odd"><td>12</td><td>AO</td><td id="2-1-12-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-12 even"><td></td><td>FF</td><td id="2-2-12-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-12 odd"><td></td><td>PFF</td><td id="2-3-12-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="separator even"><td colspan="3"></td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-13 odd"><td>13</td><td>AO</td><td id="2-1-13-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-13 even"><td></td><td>FF</td><td id="2-2-13-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-13 odd"><td></td><td>PFF</td><td id="2-3-13-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="separator even"><td colspan="3"></td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-18 odd"><td>18</td><td>AO</td><td id="2-1-18-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-18 even"><td></td><td>FF</td><td id="2-2-18-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-18 odd"><td></td><td>PFF</td><td id="2-3-18-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="separator even"><td colspan="3"></td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-19 odd"><td>19</td><td>AO</td><td id="2-1-19-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-19 even"><td></td><td>FF</td><td id="2-2-19-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
 <tr class="station-19 odd"><td></td><td>PFF</td><td id="2-3-19-am">Name goes here</td> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This structure exists on a calendar-type page where there is one table of these for each day in a month. I have some working code that uses a select list and button to filter the displayed rows.

```
  $('form#my-form').submit(function(context, settings) {
    // First, display any rows that are hidden.
    $('table#my-table tbody tr :hidden').show();
    // Get items not selected in select list and hide them.
    $('select#edit-stations').find('option').not(':selected').each(function(i, option) {
      var station_id = $(this).val();
      var station_class = '.station-' + station_id;
      $(station_class).hide().parent().find('.separator').last().hide();
    });

    // Keep form from being submitted.
    return false;

  });
```

The hiding part works like a charm. The issue I'm having is trying to also hide the last separator row that follows the last station-x row. For instance, if I hide all of the `station-18` and `station-19` rows, I also want to hide the .separator row that immediately follows the `station-13` rows. As you can see in my code, my thought was to traverse up to the parent element (`<tbody>` in this case), find all the `<tr class="separator">` elements, and hide them, but it's not working. if I put a breakpoint at that line and enter `$(station_class).hide().parent()` in the console, I just get an empty array, so apparently I'm not using .parent() incorrectly. I've also tried `.closest()` with no luck.

Am I close, or is there a better/easier way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After re-examining your code, I noticed a problem with your syntax. Specifically, this line

```
$(station_class).hide().parent().find('.separator').last().hide();
```

should be changed to

```
$(station_class).parent().find('.separator').last().hide();
```

You were calling the `hide()` method twice.

Comment: Well, that's because I'm hiding two different things: First, I want to hide the three rows with the appropriate station-x class, and then hide the following .separator row.

Comment: I see, I just thought that is the incorrect use of method chaining. I don't think `$(selector).hide()` is itself a selector. I could be wrong. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `siblings()`

```
$(station_class).hide().siblings('.separator').last().hide();
```

**Update:**

You can try with separate line code also.

```
var sep = $(station_class).hide();
sep.siblings('.separator').last().hide();
```

Comment: This is the incorrect use of chaining. You are calling `hide()` twice. My answer goes over this

Comment: OK, that makes sense, since hide() isn't a selector (as you pointed out above). It looks like I need to have two separate chains; one to hide the rows, and one to hide the last .separator row.

Comment: @RichardHamilton I really don't know, in what way it is `incorrect chain`. Can you please explain me this scenario? So that I can update my answer.

Comment: `Siblings` is a traversing method, which is to be called on a selector. `$(selector).hide()` is not a selector. Just remove the first `hide` and your code should work

Comment: I just found the documentation from w3schools. Here is the quote. `jQuery traversing, which means "move through", are used to "find" (or select) HTML elements based on their relation to other elements. Start with one selection and move through that selection until you reach the elements you desire.` http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp

Comment: @RichardHamilton While removing the first `hide()`, it is not hiding `station_class`. Hiding the `.separator` alone.

Comment: @RichardHamilton Can you please check my **Update**, where `sep` variable holding the selected(hidden) `station_class` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

before each station (except the first) generate

```
<tr class="separator station-nn"><td colspan="3"></td> </tr>
```

where nn = the station # of the following station.

Then you simply switch off the separator row when you switch off the station.

In otherwords each station has **preceeding** it, a separator that is associated with that station.  Except the first station of course...

Answer (score 0):

**Try with next() It may looks so simple and dynamic way**

> $('.station-18').hide().next('.separator').hide()

Try the demo below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.station-12').hide().next('.separator').hide();
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.station-13').hide().next('.separator').hide();
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.station-18').hide().next('.separator').hide();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Names</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="station-12 odd">
      <td>12</td>
      <td>AO</td>
      <td id="2-1-12-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-12 even">
      <td></td>
      <td>FF</td>
      <td id="2-2-12-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-12 odd">
      <td></td>
      <td>PFF</td>
      <td id="2-3-12-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separator even">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-13 odd">
      <td>13</td>
      <td>AO</td>
      <td id="2-1-13-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-13 even">
      <td></td>
      <td>FF</td>
      <td id="2-2-13-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-13 odd">
      <td></td>
      <td>PFF</td>
      <td id="2-3-13-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separator even">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-18 odd">
      <td>18</td>
      <td>AO</td>
      <td id="2-1-18-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-18 even">
      <td></td>
      <td>FF</td>
      <td id="2-2-18-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-18 odd">
      <td></td>
      <td>PFF</td>
      <td id="2-3-18-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separator even">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-19 odd">
      <td>19</td>
      <td>AO</td>
      <td id="2-1-19-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-19 even">
      <td></td>
      <td>FF</td>
      <td id="2-2-19-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="station-19 odd">
      <td></td>
      <td>PFF</td>
      <td id="2-3-19-am">Name goes here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```